# Windows and SQLite3 to Ubuntu and PostgreSQL migration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

I had my development environment in Windows, and someone suggested that I move it over from Windows to Ubuntu, as well as change the database from the stock SQLite3 to PostgreSQL. The reason was that it'd be easier to implement search.

I tried to just make it PostgreSQL in Windows, but kept hitting one error. Now that I have it up and running in Ubuntu, I'm getting the SAME error message.

20130218175105_devise_create_users.rb:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at

  ## Token authenticatable
  # t.string :authentication_token


  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
  add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

20130224193041_add_username_to_users.rb:

```
class AddUsernameToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string
  end
end
```

20130225171914_add_title_to_items.rb:

```
class AddTitleToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :items, :title, :string

  end
end
```

20130303014952_add_city_state_to_users.rb:

```
class AddCityStateToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :city, :string

    add_column :users, :state, :string

  end
end
```

database.yml:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: scratch_development
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
username: postgres
password: harley
host: localhost
```

The error:

```
mike@ubuntu:~/Sites/scratch$ rake db:migrate
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"
   -> 0.0452s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0151s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0309s
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0921s) =====================================

rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant AddUsernameToUsers
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:522:in `load_migration'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:517:in `migration'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:512:in `migrate'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:704:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:759:in `call'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:759:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:190:in `transaction'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:759:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:703:in `block in migrate'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:684:in `each'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:684:in `migrate'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `up'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:535:in `migrate'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm 99% sure that my gemfile is ok, that's why I didn't post it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to

```
rake db:schema:load
```

I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

I see the error:

```
uninitialized constant AddUsernameToUsers
```

and searching through your code I only see a class called `AddUsernameToUser`. So, that's one place to start.

Comment: I did that, thanks! Now I'm getting this... I have 'users' and 'items' that belong to them. I already successfully created the database using rake create:db:all... but not sure why the 'items' haven't been created yet. I used scaffolding, originally, to create this over in the windows environment.

==  AddTitleToItems: migrating ================================================
-- add_column(:items, :title, :string)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "items" does not exist